# Correct Syntax for running a "Run" with macro.(AutoIt)

Tags: syntax, parameters, parameter-passing, autoit

I have here a script that runs an exe file and passes a parameter `7` to it.

`Run("'C:\test\CONVERTER.exe' 7")`

This script above runs perfectly but when I add the macro `@ScriptDir`, a problem occurs.

`Run(@ScriptDir & "'\CONVERTER.exe' 7")`

It doesn't pop-up any error but I can see that the script is isn't because there is no icon in the Icon tray. I suspect that it's something about with the syntax. I can't find any documentation about this so I really need help.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take care of the quoting needed in `cmd`. Use one of the following:

```
Run(@ScriptDir & '\CONVERTER.exe 7')
Run(@ScriptDir & "\CONVERTER.exe 7")
```

If you need to quote the path/filename (because of possible spaces) in `cmd`, you have to quote the complete path/file:

```
Run('"' & @ScriptDir & '\CONVERTER.exe" 7')
```

Attention: `Run("'" & @ScriptDir & "\CONVERTER.exe' 7")` is valid AutoIt syntax, but doesn't work because the quoting for `cmd` is wrong (only `"` allowed)